# spark avoid building RDD everytime

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in S3, I am able to load data in S3 as RDD apply some changes to convert it to dataframe and run spark-sql queries. But whenever new data is added to S3, again I need to load entire data as RDD convert it to dataframe and run queries. Is there a way to avoid loading entire data and just load the new data. ie the new data should get added to RDD instead of loading entire RDD ?

Comment: Is your S3 bucket partitioned by date/time?

Comment: no i have only single bucket in which json files keeps on adding @cricket_007

Comment: Then I don't think there is a way without explicitly filtering out the files by name (assuming you include a timestamp there)

Comment: The alternative would be to use AWS lambdas to only trigger when new files are uploaded. You don't need Spark for that

Comment: He talks about adding to rdd @cricket_007

Comment: @thebluephantom I was commenting on how to "avoid building RDD everytime" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several try outs , concluded that there is no way to avoid rebuilding RDD, I am rebuilding rdd periodically so that new files in s3 will also be included in rdd.
or I can query data in s3 via glue table using spark but this is slow since for every query internally rdd/dataframe is getting constructed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at spark streaming: one of its sources monitors directories for change